# MutationObserver script in Chrome Extension couldn't catch changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to scrape a few lines of text data from a website with chrome extension. I would like to detect and log the text in a specific div class:

```
<div class="data-table">
  <div class="item-value"> Some text here </div>
  <div class="item-value"> Target text </div>
</div>
```

manifest.json:

```
{
   "name": "My Scraper",
   "version": "0.1",
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "icons": {
      "16": "icons/icon16.png",
      "48": "icons/icon48.png",
      "128": "icons/icon128.png"
   },
   "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icons/icon19.png"
   },
   "content_scripts": [{
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "matches": ["*://*.tradingview.com/*"],
      "js": [
         "lib/jquery-3.3.1.min.js",
         "content.js"
      ]
   }]
}
```

I tried MutationObserver in order to catch and log changes. This script is in `content.js` file of the extension:

```
setTimeout(function(){
   var observables = document.querySelectorAll('.item-value');
   console.log('Hello!');

   var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
      mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
         console.log(mutation);
         alert('innerText Changed!')
      });
   });

   var config = { characterData: true, subtree: true, childNodes: true };

   observables.forEach(function(node) {
      observer.observe(node, config);
   });
}, 10000);
```

The script executes 10s later after the page loads in order to be sure if target div loaded. As the result, 'Hello' text can be logged but after that nothing happens. What am i doing wrong?

The target text's div is updating frequently, but innerText changes once a minute. I need to catch the change on innerText with very low latency after that minute. If there is any option other than MutationObserver I would gladly accept it.

Comment: I can't reproduce this, although I put the observer in the page itself rather than an extension. But I'm not sure why that would make a difference.

Comment: It's a common mistake to load the content script in the wrong context or URL. It must be properly registered in manifest.json or injected via chrome.tabs.executeScript. If you're doing this correctly, I guess the site doesn't use characterData modification, but instead inserts whole nodes so you may try to use `childNodes: true` in `config`.

Comment: I've added manifest file to the question. Also added 'childNodes: true' in 'config'  
It is still not working.